# Get sender email from gmail-api

Tags: gmail-api

I am using the gmail-api and having trouble getting the email of the sender. I am talking about the "full" format of the email. I consider the email of the sender to be the one that is actually written in the "From" field using the web interface of gmail.
The headers of this full format usually include stuff like "X-Original-Authentication-Results" from which normally I can retrieve the smtp.mail value which is the sender's email but there are other emails where this header cannot be found.

This is my code so far:

```
if ("X-Original-Authentication-Results" == $header["name"]) {
        $value = $header["value"];
        preg_match("/smtp.mail=(.*)/", $value, $emailFound);
        $parsedEmail = $emailFound[1];
}
```

and here is a typical format of some headers:

```
[headers] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Delivered-To
                                [value] => randomemail@gmail.com
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Received
                                [value] => ................
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => X-Received
                                [value] => ................
                            )

                        [3] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Return-Path
                                [value] => 
                            )

                        [4] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Received
                                [value] => ................
                            )

                        [5] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Received-SPF
                                [value] => ................
                            )

                        [6] => Array
                            (
                                [name] => Authentication-Results
                                [value] => ................
                            )
........
```

So is there a solid way to get the correct email of the sender?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Loop through the headers[] array and look for the one with the 'name' = "From" (or whatever the header name is you're interested in).  Note there may be multiple headers with that name.  There are some standard headers that will usually exist (To, From, Subject) but I don't believe that's mandated by the RFC.

Comment: Thanks GmailGuy.... Unfortunately the header you suggested in this form:
[36] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => From
                                    [value] => Eva M 
                                )
but I am actually looking the email of the sender and not his name. Any idea where I can find that?

Comment: The value in the "From" header entry should be the exact contents of the email's "From" header line.  it's typically something like:

 From: "Some Name" <emailaddr@example.com>

when you "show original" in gmail web UI does it appear differently than from the API?

Comment: Yes it is different unfortunately. In the web UI is shows:
from:  Eva M <email@hotmail.com>

and above you can see the value in the api.

Comment: Is this happening on all emails or just this one?  If just this one can you look at the emails and determine what's different in the From header?  Are there any special (e.g. utf8 mime-word) characters or anything?  Not sure what you're doing for the pretty formatted printing, but are you sure it's just not hiding it because of the "<>"?

Answer (score 6):

Know this question is from a while back, but I ran into this problem recently and couldn't really find any solutions online - so thought I'd share my findings.

Basically wrapping it in the htmlentities() would do the trick - but you'd have to access the part directly; as such:-

```
$part = $message->payload['modelData']['headers'][0]['value']; 
echo htmlentities($part);
```

It seems that the API is removing the values because when you do a var_dump on the payload, the string value is actually visible.

```
 ["name"]=> string(11) "Return-Path" ["value"]=> string(21) ""
```

This works on the FROM part too. Just thought this would a much easier way to demonstrate it. :)

Comment: I was unable to get the sender email address, but that htmlentities did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I did a few experiments.
the header from API  [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get?refresh=1&pli=1&authuser=3)

**header of "From"**

```
{
    "name": "From",
    "value": "Ray Lin \u003cray@xxx.com\u003e"
 }
```

**Experiments:**

```
  foreach($headers as $header){ if($header->name==="From")  $from = $header->value;}

// experiment 1:
    preg_match('/\\\u003c(.*?)\\\u003e/', $from, $match);
    echo $match[1]; // empty


// experiment 2:(use a string instead)
    $str = 'Ray Lin \u003cray@xxx.com\u003e';
    preg_match('/\\\u003c(.*?)\\\u003e/', $str, $match);
    echo $match[1]; // ray@xxx.com

// experiment 3:
    echo $from // Ray Lin

// experiment 4:
    echo htmlentities($from) // Ray Lin <ray@xxx.com>

// experiment 5:
    preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', $from, $match);
    $from =$match[1];
    echo $from  // ray@xxx.com

// experiment 6:
    $from = htmlentities($from);
    preg_match('/<(.*?)>/', $from, $match);
    print_r($match); // empty Array()
```

experiment 5 is ideal to my need, but you can see from experiment 3, `$from` was just two words, I don't even know where the email was from.

Comment: It does not always provide the user name

Answer (score 0):

You could also loop through the headers[] array and find X-Original-Sender like `$header->name == 'X-Original-Sender'`. This works in the case the payload header contains this value.