# Efficiently get sender of e-mail from GMail API

Tags: gmail-api

I want to get the sender of all first messages in each `thread` in my G-mail inbox. To do so, it looks like I need to list all threads, fetch the thread itself with all of it's, get the first message, and then loop through its headers. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

[Get sender mail in gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33052582/get-sender-mail-in-gmail-api)

I've implemented the above and it works, but for 100 threads, it makes 1 List `thread`s request + 100 Get `thread` requests.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as of now.

You could however submit a Feature Request in the [Google Issue Tracker](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker) and ask that the `Gmail.Users.threads:list` method get an option to retrieve the first message of each thread.