# Gmail API - Get sender name

Tags: python, gmail-api

I want to get the string that the user entered as his sender name when sending emails. I can get this from the message API, however it changes sometimes when e.g. the user sends an email through a service like Google Slides. I need the value the user entered manually when he set up his account. What is the best way to get this value?

Comment: It seems that the solution you're looking for has been resolved in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781501/get-sender-email-from-gmail-api).

Comment: Unfortunately not. This is exactly what I was referring to when using the message API. The value if not always the same, because there are tool connected to the user's account that use a different From text. Therefore I need to either get this value directly from the API, or need to know if the message was sent by the user directly and not by another tool.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use another API endpoint. You need to send GET request to this url: https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/MAIN_EMAIL_OF_USER/settings/sendAs/EMAIL_THAT_WILL_BE_USED_FOR_SENDING

If you use python library provided by google you can use this endpoint:

```
service.users().settings().sendAs().get(userId='MAIN_EMAIL_OF_USER', sendAsEmail='EMAIL_THAT_WILL_BE_USED_FOR_SENDING')
```

More about `sendAs` user settings in Gmail API you can find here: 
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/sendAs