# How to have a known name as From using Gmail API

Tags: gmail-api

When sending with the GMail API, my email source contains something like that:

```
Received: from 13936824666 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST;
```

How to have a known name displayed instead of unknown?

**EDIT**: The from name/email display properly in the rendering of the email, that's not the question.

It's what's in the source that's annoying.

Check an email sent using the normal SMTP of Gmail:

```
Received: from localhost:3000 (47.150.198.178.dynamic.wline.res.cust.swisscom.ch [178.198.150.47])
by ismtpd0003p1lon1.sendgrid.net (SG) with ESMTP id PWjjmKwxTeS34YOHk6LJJQ
Mon, 30 May 2016 12:51:24.673 +0000 (UTC)
```

From a 3rd party sender (SendGrid)

```
Received: from gmail.com (47.150.198.178.dynamic.wline.res.cust.swisscom.ch. [178.198.150.47])
    by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id v125sm11247946wmv.17.2016.05.30.05.55.56
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Mon, 30 May 2016 05:55:56 -0700 (PDT)
```

And now through Gmail **API**

```
Received: from 13936824666 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST;
Mon, 30 May 2016 08:57:04 -0400
```

Comment: As you interested in that value in particular, or who sent the message? You could check the `From`-header if it contains what you need.

Comment: What programming language? You have to construct a proper email, with the proper headers, have a quick read at RFC 822 (superseded but has all the info you need)

Comment: Heya I think you have similar issue with [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781501/get-sender-email-from-gmail-api). Check it out :)

Comment: @noogui Nope, nothing to do with this. My from name *displays* properly in Gmail, but the *original text* does have this line I display that I can't explain.

Comment: I enriched the question so we can better see the difference.

Comment: @Jeremy Did you find the answer?

Comment: @Jeremy Did you find the answer?

Comment: I did not.......