# Gmail API - detecting if an email was sent by a 3rd party tool

Tags: gmail-api, email-headers

I am retrieving the header information of emails through the Gmail API and would like to know if an email was sent manually or through a 3rd party tool like e.g. an email campaigning tool or some other tool that sends emails for the user.

I suspect that I can do this with the Received field, which seems to give some information on how the email was sent. However it is not clear how I should understand this information or what structure Google uses for this field. Does anyone have more information on this?

Some examples of values that this field returns (IP addresses and IDs changed):

```
"from 13933457865 named unknown by gmailapi.google.com with HTTPREST; Tue, 13 Sep 2016 07:49:15 -0700"

"from [127.0.0.1] (ec5-42-77-39-231.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com. [10.00.00.221]) by smtp.gmail.com with ESMTPSA id ak3sm22356856pad.19.2016.10.06.04.16.13 (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128); Thu, 06 Oct 2016 04:16:13 -0700 (PDT)"

"by 10.00.00.200 with HTTP; Tue, 20 Sep 2016 18:42:24 -0700 (PDT)"
```

Comment: Check this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781501/get-sender-email-from-gmail-api?rq=1) if it can help you.

Comment: Thanks @KENdi, unfortunately this refers to the From field, and not the Received field.