# gmail api strait forward way to get sender email

Tags: php, gmail-api

I’m having problems getting the sender's email address,

```
$single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $msg_id);
```

"from" usually yields the senders name

To get the email address I have this code

```
if($partes->getName() == 'Authentication-Results')
{
    $outh_res = $partes->getValue();
    if(strpos($outh_res, 'smtp.mailfrom=') !== false)
    {
        $bits = explode('smtp.mailfrom=',$outh_res);
        $mail = $bits[1];
        if(strpos($mail, ';') !== false)
        {
            $bits = explode(';',$mail);
            $mail = str_replace('"', '',$bits[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

That always gives me an email, but when the sender is behind mail chimp (or their own servers (postfix)) for example: bounces+2063633-785c-info=myemail.com@sg1.senderemail.com

In the best case I receive @sendermail.com (from gmail itself I know its info@sendermail.com) so it's useless
In some cases

```
if($partes->getName() == 'Reply-To')
{
    $other_mail = str_replace('"', '',$partes->getValue());
}
```

Gives me a helpful email others just the senders name

as suggested in [github php gmail api issue # 521](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/issues/521) and other places

```
$only_header = $gmail->users_messages->get('me',$msg_id, ['format' => 'metadata', 'metadataHeaders' => ['To','X-Original-To','X-Original-From','From','Reply-To','Subject']]);
```

It gives exactly the same info.

Is there any way that the api gives me exactly the sender email address even if it's behind mail chimp or other 3rd party sender?

There's a similar answer [Get sender email from gmail-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24781501/get-sender-email-from-gmail-api), I already loop the headers and tried zingzinco's answer.

Edit: Thanks to Joey Tawadrous;

Php code:

```
if($partes->getName() == 'From')
{
    $raw_from = $partes->getValue();
    if(strpos($raw_from, '<') !== false)
    {
        $bit = explode('<',$raw_from);
        $bit2 = explode('>',$bit[1]);
        $final_email = $bit2[0];
        $sender_name = str_replace('"', '',$bit[0]);
    }
    else 
    {
        $sender_name = limpiarm(str_replace('"', '',$raw_from));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var email = '';

var messageFrom = _.where(message.payload.headers, {name: 'From'})[0].value;

    if(messageFrom.includes('<')) {
        var fromObj = messageFrom.split('<');
        email = fromObj[1];

        fromObj = email.split('>');
        email = fromObj[0];
    }


return email;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! (Though why doesn’t the <mail@mail.com> show up in print nor in dump?[php])